# String Validation error during Counter Query on Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-storm, hector

I have the following Counter Query on my code:

```
private CounterSlice<String> queryLastCounts(Long key, String columnFamily,
                                                            int maxLength) {
    SliceCounterQuery<Long, String> query = 
            HFactory.createCounterSliceQuery(cassandra.getKeyspace(), 
                                                            LONG_S, STRING_S);
    query
        .setColumnFamily(columnFamily)
        .setKey(key)
        .setRange("", "", true, maxLength);
    return query.execute().get();
}
```

On my unit tests the code works perfectly. But when running the proper application (I'm using storm for that) I get the following error:

```
Caused by: InvalidRequestException(why:String didn't validate.)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$get_slice_result.read(Cassandra.java:7756)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_get_slice(Cassandra.java:570)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.get_slice(Cassandra.java:542)
at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.KeyspaceServiceImpl$8.execute(KeyspaceServiceImpl.java:308)
... 25 more
```

I'm also using Hector for accessing Cassandra.

Comment: Can you paste the schema for the column family you are using? Is the key_validation_class set to LongType?

Comment: I was creating the Column Counter using the UTF8 for validation, changed to LONG and solved the issue. Thx

Comment: The strange thing is that it worked on unit tests o.O but not on the proper running jar.

Comment: it would be nice to post an answer to this question (either @Richard or  yourself in order to explain your how to solve this problem in wich one might bump.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Ar3s here is the solution to this problem.

I was leaving my column validators as default, which uses UTF8 for it. The solution was to change it to the Long validator and all went ok.

The lesson here is:

> Check your Data Validator for the column in question.